# Openlayers and not visible marker into popup

Tags: dictionary, popup, openlayers, marker

I have one problem with my OpenLayers map. When i click marker on map it will show popup but other markers are still visible above this popup.

How do this in correct way?

```
    fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
    toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); 

    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );

    markers.events.register('mouseover', markers, function(evt) {
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup",
                new OpenLayers.LonLat(Tlon,Tlat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection),
            null,
            '<span style="z-index:99999;background:red;">sdf</span>',
            null,
            false);
        map.addPopup(popup);
    });

    markers.events.register('mouseout', markers, function(evt) {popup.hide();});

    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(Tlon,Tlat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection),icon));
```

Comment: Give a little more information please. How did you implement the popups? Do you maybe use framed cloud popups?http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Popup/FramedCloud-js.html

Comment: Is there a URL we could see to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Without a URL to test, I can't be sure, but you may need to clone your icon for each marker you add to the map.  From the docs:

> Note that if you pass an icon into the Marker constructor, it will
>   take that icon and use it.  This means that you should not share icons
>   between markers -- you use them once, but you should clone() for any
>   additional markers using that same icon.